# How to check the condition and pass extra parameter to the semantic-ui search?

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, semantic-ui

I am working in a search module. I have a text field of class UI & search. When I start to type it will call this URL and get the result.

Now I have a new requirement. When I start to type I want to check the condition. If that condition is true then I want to pass a new parameter to this URL and if the condition is false then continue the process.

I am trying to find out how to check the condition in below function before calling URL and passing the params.

### HTML

```
<div class="ui search">
        <input class="prompt" type="text" placeholder="Search Here....">
        <i class="search icon"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

### JS

```
$('.ui.search').search({
    apiSettings: {
        url: '/api/v2/demo/suggest?q={query}',
        onResponse: function (res) {
            console.log("res", res);
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: share you HTML code also

Comment: @NullPointer I have updated the question

Comment: from which external js this **.search** is refered?means external library for js

Comment: @NullPointer yes Semantic UI - Search http://github.com/semantic-org/semantic-ui/

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do using `Behaviors` of `Form Validation`

```
$('.foo').form('behavior name', argumentOne, argumentTwo)
```

**Validating Programmatically**

Form validation provides additional behaviors to programmatically trigger validation for either the form or an individual field, and check validation on the form or individual fields.

https://semantic-ui.com/behaviors/form.html#behaviors